# How to compare List<MyClass> dynamically for differences

Tags: c#, list, dynamic, comparison

I got my class `User` which contains different properties such as `bool`, `int`, ...
Before working with my list I saved an original copy of it in order to determine wether I need to serialize at the end of the program or not.

So how can I compare those two lists? I'd like to have something like this

```
if (Users.Compare<User>(this.OrigCfg.Users))
    // they are equal
```

Here is my class

```
public class User
{
    private List<Branch> branches;
    internal string login;
    internal string sourcePath;
    internal string pathOnce;
    internal string destPath;
    internal UserTypes userType;
    internal bool? copy;
    internal bool? delete;
    internal int? taskTimeout;
    internal bool? deleteZip;
    internal int? availableSpaceLimit;
}
```

`Branch` is another class of mine which only contains a `string` property (yet). `UserTypes` is an enum of four types.

I already tried several things posted on Stackoverflow, but they seemed not to work for me. I'm also searching for a way to compare to user classes for differences but couldn't find anything fitting sadly.

Comment: Did you check this url: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42839/Sorting-Lists-using-IComparable-and-IComparer-Inte

Comment: I want to avoid addressing every member. If I add another member I need to keep in mind editing the compare method. Would be nice if I hadn't.

Comment: But there should be a property that can be able to distinguish two given user's. You will be implementing this logic for a couple of fields and not for each and every field in a class.

Comment: I'm not getting what you mean. How can I implement it for `int`, `string`, ...? I explicitly have to write `myUser.login` to compare it. I don't want it like this because I need to care about this method everytime I make changes in my `User` class.

Comment: Being that case, you can opt to go with reflection to identify the propertyNames and values and then perform a comparison, a generic one

Comment: So this was my question Mr. Guy...